# Set of polynomials being an ideal

Tags: polynomials, ideals

> Are all polynomials {$P \in\Bbb Q(X)\mid P(1)=P(3)=0$} an ideal? If so find the monic generator.

$\Bbb Q$ is the rationals here and I know that the above set is an ideal by writing out multiplication of an element from Q(x) and an element from the set which shows me when x=1 or x=3, the multiplication result is still 0., but how do i figure out the generator?  I do not know where to start.

Comment: If you add two polynomials in that set, is the result in that set?  If you multiply a polynomial by a polynomial in that set, is the result in that set?

Comment: that means that $(x-1)(x-3)$ divides your polynomial $P.$

Comment: Can you write down a single polynomial with roots at $1$ and $3$?

Comment: so i figured out it is an ideal by writing out multiplication of an element from Q(x) and an element from the set just now, but how do i figure out the generator?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Do some polynomial arithmetic:

$$ P(\alpha)=0\iff P(X)\text{ is divisible by }\enspace X-\alpha. $$

Also, $\mathbf Q[X]$, like all polynomial rings over a field, is a P.I.D. so you can apply Euclid's lemma, $X-\alpha$ being irreducible.

Comment: so i figured out why it is an ideal and edited my answer, but i still dont know how to figure out the generator--like you said thought, it is a PID, so it is a single generator

Comment: nvm, i did figure out the generator myself, but it is not a single element but a minimal polynomial so the set above is not PID, so why diid you mention PID here? thanks

Comment: All ideals of a polynomial ring over a field are principal and when I read your post you mentioned two generators. Anyway  the main argument to determine the generator, with hint O give, relies on Euclid's lemma.